# SendGrid free plan is not listed Select Plan dropdown

Tags: ibm-cloud, sendgrid

we are developing services on IBM Bluemix and are working in multiple Bluemix orgs.  We’ve noticed recently that the SendGrid free plan no longer is available (isn’t listed in the Select Plan dropdown).   We see only Bronze, Silver, Gold, Platinum.  Is this a bug?  Was the free plan intentionally removed? @BenRondeau et al.
Thanks!..  Duane

Answer (score 2):

The SendGrid free plan in Bluemix is temporarily unavailable for maintenance per the Bluemix status page:

http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus

Here is the maintenance text for your convenience:

> Maintenance: SendGrid service - US South and United Kingdom regions
>   The SendGrid 3rd party service has been removed from the catalog
>   temporarily for maintenance. This page will be updated when that
>   maintenance is complete.  Users can not create new instances of the
>   service during this time. Existing instances will continue to work as
>   expected.
>
> Update 2016-02-19 19:03 UTC: Maintenance of the paid SendGrid plan
>   offerings is complete and those plans have been restored to the US
>   South, United Kingdom regions.  The team is working to restore the
>   free plan as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi again.  Is there an ETA for when the SendGrid free plan will be available again in Bluemix? @AlexdaSilva

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an ETA for that. This depends on SendGrid team only, not Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the integration is with Bluemix, and if there's an interface within orgs for SendGrid that you're referring to, but you can easily get it the old fashion way: from the settings page on SendGrid's site. I made a free account just yesterday and am currently using it today without being billed.

If you need help navigating their site, they have a page dedicated to their [free plan](https://sendgrid.com/free).

Just click the <kbd>Try for free</kbd> button. It takes you to a [modal page](https://sendgrid.com/pricing?id=8b9ae93b-ce8a-11e4-b4e5-5fcde71ee009&s=1) where you can add your credentials and sign up. :)

Comment: Thanks @Seth - this will be our backup plan.